# xargs remove file name containing $

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, shell, xargs

I am using xargs to remove files from remote server.

```
xargs -a /var/log/del.log -i -exec  ssh root@abc.com 'rm  -rf "{}"'
```

`del.log` contains path of the files which are deleted on local server and I want to delete them on remote server. Every thing is working fine but problem starts when their is a temoprary office file like `~$excel.xlsx` when file naming  like this occur xargs makes the command like.

```
ssh root@abc.com 'rm -rf "~.xlxs"'  - which is wrong,
```

It should be like - `ssh root@abc.com 'rm -rf "~$excel.xlxs"'`

Why xargs is doing like this? May be xargs is excepting it as variable. I need some solutions please.

Or is there a better way to delete files from remote server? Provided the local server has the list of path which need to be deleted on remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xargs -a /var/log/del.log -i -exec  ssh root@abc.com 'rm  -rf "{}"'
```

Swap the single quotes and the double quotes:

```
xargs -a /var/log/del.log -i -exec  ssh root@abc.com "rm  -rf '{}'"
```

then the command will be expand to:

```
ssh root@abc.com "rm -rf '~$excel.xlxs'"
```

and it works fine because:

[**`man bash`**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> Enclosing  characters in single quotes preserves the literal value
>   of each character within the quotes.  A single quote    may not occur
>   between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
>
> Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value
>   of all characters within the quotes, with the  excep‐    tion of $, `,
>   \, and, when history expansion is enabled, !.  The characters $ and`
>   retain their special meaning within    double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

The shell is interpreting the word following the `$` sign and preceding the `.` as a variable. Since the `$excel`is not set as a variable and not an environment variable either, the shell is replacing it with an empty string. So

```
  ~$excel.xlxs  ==>  ~.xlxs     when you replace the variable with an empty string.
```

To remediate this, you need to precede the dollar sign with an `escape character \` -

```
   rm -rf ~\$excel.xlsx
```

Comment: Thanks for Good advice this is nice solution but Quanta's suggested solution works fine.